# Java reflection for library classes

Tags: java, javafx

I have a class with a large number of variables for which I use `MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields()` and a loop to save the simple types such as int, double etc.

Now I'm stuck on the 'not so simple ones' such as `javafx.scene.paint.Color`, `javafx.scene.effect.InnerShadow` etc.

Can I save those values somehow using `MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields()` or do I need to save them separately (i.e. manually)?

Comment: Why don't you try yourself and check out if it is possible ;)

Comment: what do you mean by 'save', what are trying to achieve?

Comment: ItachiUchiha - I have tried for several hours now, but cannot find a solution and Google is no help. I wouldn't be asking without having tried first!

Comment: I need to save the state of my Class (it's a JavaFX 8 graphical design package I'm writing). I save the state (all the variables) to an XML file, which is then transmitted to a remote location. There is used to re-render the screen. I tried Serializable, but ran into too may problems (JavaFX 8 doesn't appear to be serial-friendly). Hope someone can help

Comment: Did you check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033943/serialize-javafx-components

Comment: You might also consider using a mapping/serialization framework such as Dozer (http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/about.html), instead of implementing one yourself. Of course it depends on how many objects you need to serialize.

Comment: Thanks Mick - same problem though. As soon as Color, InnerShadow etc are used, you run into serialization problems, so the solution suggested there won't work.

Comment: The Kryo library (https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo/blob/master/README.md#serializers) could also be worth a try.

Comment: Dozer looks very interesting! Hadn't come across it, so I'll check it out :-)

Comment: If you have to output XML, then perhaps XStream (http://xstream.codehaus.org/) would suit you best.