# Serialize a Circle[][]?

Tags: java, serialization, geometry

I have a pixel editor app and I need to save to a file the pixelArray created.  Serializing the pixelArray of Circle objects seems like the practical solution so I create the following class:

```
public class PixelArray implements Serializable{
    static Circle[][] pixelArray;
    public static  Circle[][] pixArray (int row, int col){
        pixelArray = new Circle[row][col];
        return pixelArray;
    }
}
```

The SaveFile class includes a JFileChooser and saveFile method for to Serialize the pixelArray as follows:

public class SaveFile {

```
public static void write(){
    String fileName;
    fileName = "PixelArray1.pix";
    JFileChooser fileDialog = new JFileChooser( "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Visual Art\\Playlist\\");
    File selectedFile = new File(fileName);
    fileDialog.setSelectedFile(selectedFile);
    fileDialog.setDialogTitle("Save Pixel File");
    fileDialog.setSelectedFile(null);
    fileDialog.setSize(400, 400);
    fileDialog.setVisible(true);
    int option = fileDialog.showSaveDialog(null);
    if(option != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        return;                                         //user canceled of clicked the dialog's close box
    selectedFile = fileDialog.getSelectedFile();
    if(selectedFile.exists()){                          //ask the user to replace this file
        int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"The file \""+ selectedFile.getName() +
        "\" already exists.\nDo you want to replace it?",
        "Confirm Save",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE );
        if(response != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) return;  //user does not want ot replace the fle
    }
    saveFile(pixelArray, "PixelArray1.pix");                 //Serialize
}

public static void saveFile(Circle[][] pixelArray, String fileName){      //Serialize
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        out.writeObject(pixelArray);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Try as I may as a newbie, I can't get past the exception:

*java.io.NotSerializableException: javafx.scene.shape.Circle*

Serializing a Circle[][] shouldn't be that hard; what am I missing, please?

Comment: Node - Shape - Circle: these don't implement Serializable.

Comment: Check [11033943](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033943/serialize-javafx-components) or consider serializing a structure that you can create your circles from.

Comment: You may want to extend the Circle class to make it implement Serializable, and use that class in your PixelArray class

Comment: Graphics objects tend to be rather heavy. I'd think that a pixel doesn't need more data than a colour and (perhaps) a coordinate pair.

Comment: @AlbertoSaito Now that would create a heavy burden of responsibility for this subclass...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you should read documentation of the specific exception, it states:

> Thrown when an instance is required to have a `Serializable` interface. The serialization runtime or the class of the instance can throw this exception. The argument should be the name of the class.

This because [Java serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) requires to tag classes which are supposed to be serializable with the `Serializable` interface:

```
class Circle implements Serializable
{
  ...
}
```

If the class you are working on is not modifiable, then you must provide your own bridge class, eg:

```
class SerializableCircle implements Serializable
{
  // create a serializable circle from a Circle
  SerializableCircle(Circle circle) {
    ..
  }

  // create a Circle back from an unserialized circle
  Circle unserialize()
  {
    ..
  }
};
```

and then serialize and unserialize this.

Answer (score 0):

Since `javafx.scene.shape.Circle` is not serializable, you need to serialize something that is actually serializable.

To accomplish this, you could write a wrapper class who implements Serializable that has all the data needed to recreate a circle object when it is deserialized.

Here's something that should help with making a serializable class: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=45

Answer (score 0):

Now, I believe from the **Answers** given, it would be more practical to drop **Serialization** and figure out how to convert my Circle[][] to a Color[].  Then I would need to read/write Color[] to a file to Save/Open and send via Wi-Fi to microcontroller.