# How to serialize for javafx shapes object?

Tags: serialization, javafx

I'm making a drawing editor using the shapes objects.

I don't use canvas API, because need to map the shapes objects and function data.

But the problem is save/load shapes objects. Through search, understood why can't serialize. So then, how to save/load shapes objects?

Do you know alternative way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialize JavaFX components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033943/serialize-javafx-components)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163872/how-to-serialize-a-non-serializable-in-java