# JavaFX Export Scene as PDF/SVG

Tags: image, pdf, svg, export, javafx-8

I have currently developed an ultimately open source application to analyse some data in a table view and visualise the resulting data in some additional plots. A problematic thing with this is, that the generated plots could potentially be useful for end users for e.g. a presentation, further downstream informative discussion and so on. This is why I started working on an export function using ImageWriter

```
//adding a context menu item to the chart
    final MenuItem saveAsPng = new MenuItem("Save as png");
    saveAsPng.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            int scale = 6; //6x resolution should be enough, users should downscale if required
            final Bounds bounds = bc.getLayoutBounds();
            final SnapshotParameters spa = new SnapshotParameters();
            spa.setTransform(javafx.scene.transform.Transform.scale(scale, scale));
            ImageWriter imageWriter = new ImageWriter();
            try {
                imageWriter.saveImage(stage, bc.snapshot(spa, null));
            } catch (ImageException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

This successfully creates a PNG file with sufficient size, but my ideal solution would be to export in vector-based format, e.g. PDF/SVG. For Swing applications, I knew how to achieve this, but for JFX I couldn't really find a proper solution for that matter. I already investigated several potential ideas, e.g. using a printer dialogue and then exporting as a PDF via virtual printer, but that does result in a bitmap inside the PDF, too.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Related: [Serialize JavaFX components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033943/serialize-javafx-components)

Comment: @w3b1x, do you have any updates on this?

Comment: Hi @schrieveslaach, no I couldn't find a working solution for this particular issue and neither found anybody able to help with it either. Asked around even on a small conference with some Java experts and nobody had a clue. Seems to be something that is not really done ... probably someone would have to write a library for this particular problem.