# Save/Load a Pane drawing on JavaFx

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, save, pane

I have created a paint application where I draw shapes and add them as nodes to the Pane. Something similar to the code below:

```
currentShape = new Rectangle();
shapeList.add(currentShape);
pane.getChildren().addAll(shapelist);
```

I want to save a drawing and be able to load that saved drawing. I am not sure how to approach this. I looked at examples using Snapshots/Writable Image of the following sort. However this gives me a `Cannot Resolve SwingFXUtils` error

```
save.setOnAction(event -> {
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

            //Set extension filter
            fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("png files (*.png)", "*.png"));

            //Prompt user to select a file
            File f = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);

            if(f != null){
                try {
                    //Pad the capture area
                    WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage((int) pane.getWidth(), (int) pane.getHeight());
                    pane.snapshot(null, writableImage);
                    RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(writableImage, null);
                    //Write the snapshot to the chosen file
                    ImageIO.write(renderedImage, "png", f);
                } catch (IOException ex)
                { ex.printStackTrace(); }

            }
        });
```

If anyone has a better suggestion on how to save and load a drawing on a pane, I would appreciate it.

Comment: You need to import SwingFXUtils, like any other class whose methods you want to call.  As for saving, if you just save a snapshot, you will lose all information about the individual shapes;  is that acceptable to you?

Comment: Importing SwingFXUtils like `import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;` gives me the following error `Cannot resolve symbol embed`. And no I want to retain that information as I need to load the same shapes

Comment: If you're using JavaFX 9+, note `SwingFXUtils` is in the `javafx.swing` module which must be resolved on the module-path and, if your code is modular, required by your module. But a snapshot is not the correct approach. You should have designed a model that _represents_ what's displayed on screen. It's the model that you save. How exactly you do that is up to you. For instance, you could save the model state to an XML or JSON file. When you load the XML/JSON file you _rebuild_ the model and _then_ you create the view based on the state of the model.

Comment: Related question: [Serialize JavaFX components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033943/serialize-javafx-components).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slaw is right:  The best approach by far is to create your own model objects which represent what is shown in your application.

But, if you want to try writing and reading JavaFX Shapes directly, you do have an option:  XML bean serialization.

XML bean serialization is performed by the [XMLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) and [XMLDecoder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/XMLDecoder.html) classes.

Unlike regular Java serialization, they don’t look at fields, only bean properties.  A bean property is defined by a public read-method, which is a zero-argument method that starts with `get` (or, if it returns a primitive `boolean`, it may optionally start with `is` instead of `get`).

Thus, the presence of a `getWidth()` method defines a property named `width`.

If there is a corresponding `set` method (in the above case, it would be `setWidth`), which takes exactly one argument of the same type returned by the get-method, the property is defined as a writable property.

(The full rules are a little more complex than this;  I’ve only described the general case.  The full JavaBeans specification is [here](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/).)

If you’ve looked at the [javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/index.html) for JavaFX, you’ve probably noticed that JavaFX classes have a lot of properties defined.  This means you can save your `pane` children with something like this:

```
private static final java.nio.file.Path SAVE_FILE_LOCATION =
    Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "shapes.xml");

void save()
throws IOException {
    try (XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(
        new BufferedOutputStream(
            Files.newOutputStream(SAVE_FILE_LOCATION)))) {

        encoder.setExceptionListener(e -> {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        });

        encoder.writeObject(pane.getChildren().toArray(new Node[0]));
    }
}

void load()
throws IOException {
    try (XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(
        new BufferedInputStream(
            Files.newInputStream(SAVE_FILE_LOCATION)))) {

        decoder.setExceptionListener(e -> {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        });

        pane.getChildren().setAll((Node[]) decoder.readObject());
    }
}
```

However, there are limits on what XMLEncoder can know and intuit about a class.  For instance, in the above code, I am using an array of `Node` rather than the raw ObservableList, because XMLEncoder doesn’t know how to serialize any of the (not publicly documented) concrete implementations of ObservableList.  XMLEncoder does, however, have the built-in ability to serialize arrays, as long as it can serialize the array elements themselves.

A more significant issue is that it doesn’t know how to serialize some properties and will just ignore them.  For example, Color is not a typical Java bean:  it is read-only, so while XMLEncoder can read its data, there are no set-methods, so the encoder doesn’t know what instructions to write that a future XMLDecoder would be able to use to create an equivalent Color object.

We can customize an XMLEncoder by [providing it with custom PersistenceDelegates](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/Encoder.html#setPersistenceDelegate(java.lang.Class,java.beans.PersistenceDelegate)).  Conveniently, the [DefaultPersistenceDelegate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/DefaultPersistenceDelegate.html) subclass allows bean property names to be passed to the constructor, which creates a delegate that will tell XMLDecoder to look for a constructor which takes an argument corresponding to each of those properties in the originally written data.

Since Color has [a four-argument constructor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#%3Cinit%3E(double,double,double,double)) that takes the values of the [red](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#getRed()), [green](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#getGreen()), [blue](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#getBlue()), and [opacity](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#getOpacity()) properties, we can add a DefaultPersistenceDelegate to an XMLEncoder, which instructs future XMLDecoders to use those properties’ values when reconstituting a Color object:

```
encoder.setPersistenceDelegate(Color.class,
    new DefaultPersistenceDelegate(
        new String[] { "red", "green", "blue", "opacity" }));
```

The above means:  “When writing a Color object, write instructions for future decoders to look for a constructor in the Color class that takes four doubles, then write the actual values to pass in the future by calling the Color object’s getRed, getGreen, getBlue, and getOpacity methods respectively.”

If you expect your shapes will include [Text](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/Text.html) objects, you can add a persistence delegate for the [Font](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/Font.html) class:

```
encoder.setPersistenceDelegate(Font.class,
    new DefaultPersistenceDelegate(
        new String[] { "name", "size" }));
```

And you can also add persistence delegates for the other Paint implementations:

```
encoder.setPersistenceDelegate(LinearGradient.class,
    new DefaultPersistenceDelegate(new String[] {
        "startX", "startY", "endX", "endY",
        "proportional", "cycleMethod", "stops"
    }));
encoder.setPersistenceDelegate(RadialGradient.class,
    new DefaultPersistenceDelegate(new String[] {
        "focusAngle", "focusDistance", "centerX", "centerY",
        "radius", "proportional", "cycleMethod", "stops"
    }));
```

(I have deliberately omitted ImagePattern, because while representing an Image in XML is possible, it is ugly and inefficient.  If you intend to store images, XML is not a good storage format.)

So, the updated version of the load and store methods looks like this:

```
private static void addPersistenceDelegatesTo(Encoder encoder) {
    encoder.setPersistenceDelegate(Font.class,
        new DefaultPersistenceDelegate(
            new String[] { "name", "size" }));
    encoder.setPersistenceDelegate(Color.class,
        new DefaultPersistenceDelegate(
            new String[] { "red", "green", "blue", "opacity" }));
    encoder.setPersistenceDelegate(LinearGradient.class,
        new DefaultPersistenceDelegate(new String[] {
            "startX", "startY", "endX", "endY",
            "proportional", "cycleMethod", "stops"
        }));
    encoder.setPersistenceDelegate(RadialGradient.class,
        new DefaultPersistenceDelegate(new String[] {
            "focusAngle", "focusDistance", "centerX", "centerY",
            "radius", "proportional", "cycleMethod", "stops"
        }));
}

private static final java.nio.file.Path SAVE_FILE_LOCATION =
    Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "shapes.xml");

void save()
throws IOException {
    try (XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(
        new BufferedOutputStream(
            Files.newOutputStream(SAVE_FILE_LOCATION)))) {

        encoder.setExceptionListener(e -> {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        });

        addPersistenceDelegatesTo(encoder);

        encoder.writeObject(pane.getChildren().toArray(new Node[0]));
    }
}

void load()
throws IOException {
    try (XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(
        new BufferedInputStream(
            Files.newInputStream(SAVE_FILE_LOCATION)))) {

        decoder.setExceptionListener(e -> {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        });

        pane.getChildren().setAll((Node[]) decoder.readObject());
    }
}
```